# More than one parameter inside equalsIgnoreCase() method

Tags: java, if-statement, equals

I would like to clean up my code when i use the equals method. I was wondering if there is any way to add more parameters inside the equals() method at once.

Currently, it is looking something like this:

```
if (myString.equalsIgnoreCase("option1") || 
    myString.equalsIgnoreCase("option2") || 
    myString.equalsIgnoreCase("option3"))
        doSomething();
```

While I want it like this:

```
if (myString.equalsIgnoreCase("option1", "option2", "option3"))
       doSomething();
```

Is there anything I can do? Like override the equals() method or something like that?

Comment: yes you could store them in a list or some other java collection type and then check that

Comment: `if (Stream.of("option1", "option2", "option3").anyMatch(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(myString)))`

Comment: That's not an equals implementation @BheshGurung

Comment: Because the OP wrote that multiple times @BheshGurung. He's looking for `equalsIgnoreCase`, not an class' equals method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Stream.anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
if (Stream.of("option1", "option2", "option3").anyMatch(myString::equalsIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a List (or similar) with possible values, then check if it contains your string

```
List<String> foo = Arrays.asList("opt1", "opt2", "opt3");
String bar = "OPT1";
if (foo.contains(bar.toLowerCase())) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would to create an `EqualityUtil` and then create then following:

```
public final class EqualityUtil {

    private EqualityUtil() {}

    public static boolean equalsIgnoreCaseAnyOf(String theString, String... theStrings) {
        return Arrays.stream(theStrings).anyMatch(theString::equalsIgnoreCase);
    }

}
```

With this you can simply pass in a string and a N numbers of strings to to your job. Plus it's a utility class meaning that this can be reused around the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to write something of your own, I'd probably do something like this:

```
public boolean equalsMultiple (Object myValue, Object [] objects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length - 1; i++) {
        if (myValue.equals(objects[i]))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and use Object as the parameters in case you wanted to use that method again with an Object other than a String. Then you could use it like this:

```
    Object [] objects = new String [] {"option1","option2",
            "option3"};
    String myString = "option1";
    System.out.println(equalsMultiple(myString,objects));
```